# Can product objects in a category be exited?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a category $\textbf{C}$ with objects $A$, $B$, and $A \times B$.

Is it guranteed that for every morphism $f : A \rightarrow X$ there is a morphism $f' : A \times B \rightarrow X$, or equivalently, that there is a morphism $\text{id}'_X : A \times B \rightarrow A$?

Comment: Unique how?.....

Comment: removed. unique in that there is a bijection from the set of morphisms f:A→X to the set of morphisms f′:A×B→X

Comment: Think about sets.  This is very false:  map points in $B$ to a single point.  A single map $A \to X$ will have multiple maps $A \times B \to X$.

Comment: Hmm, right. The question as it is now still stands though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product $A\times B$ is **by definition** accompanied by projection morphism $\pi_1\colon A\times B\to A$ and $\pi_2\colon A\times B\to B$.

So if there exists a morphism $f\colon A\to X$, we readily find a morphism $f\circ \pi_1\colon A\times B\to X$.